# Comparing a two lists to see if there are enough characters?

Tags: java, string, oop, string-comparison

So i was writing some code and have to take a bucket being a list of characters bucket: "AASDJBDHBDADBIWDBEDUBDCECM" and a sign: " hot dogs are on sale" and seeing if there are enough characters in bucket to complete the sign.

I've gotten this far but when i try to replace the characters with a different element, it doesn't want to work. I can't seem to get the comparison right.

Any ideas

Class 1

```
 package question2;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ShopSign {
 //public String statement;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    PromptUser promptuser= new PromptUser(input);

    Bucket bucket=new Bucket(input);

    new Checker(bucket.Bucket,promptuser.message);
    }
  }
```

Class 2

```
 package question2;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Bucket {
 public String Bucket;

 public Bucket(Scanner input){
    System.out.print("Enter the bucket of characters");
    Bucket= input.nextLine();

    }

 }
```

Class 3

```
 package question2;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class PromptUser {
 public String message;

 public PromptUser(Scanner input){
    System.out.print("Enter proposed message:");
    message= input.nextLine();      

    }

 }
```

Class 4

```
 package question2;

 public class Checker {
 public Checker(String bucket,String promptuser){
    for (int i=0; i<promptuser.length();i++){
        if(bucket.indexOf(promptuser.charAt(i)> -1)){
            bucket.replace(promptuser.charAt(i), "in the");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("User out: " + promptuser.charAt(i));
            }

        }

     }
  }
```

Comment: `String` is immutable, it can't be changed.  You could use a `StringBuilder` instead

Comment: Maybe it's unrelated, but please don't name your variable inside the class `Bucket` as `Bucket`. Names should be more unique than that.

Comment: Don't keep your bucket as a String, that's inefficient.
Just throw all the letters into a HashMap with a count for each letter, and then go through your String, reducing the counter for each letter

Comment: That may be true but the problem is that if I wanted to use an array I would have to define the array size but can't because it isn't given, and I can't use array lost because I never covered it so I'm unsure how to use anything but string. Also is it really true you can compare a string and replace an element of it?

Comment: Also, `String` comparison in Java is case sensitve

Comment: To define array with size idenfity in runtime:
char[] a = new char[bucket.length()];
To convert to array of chars:
bucket.toCharArray() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: yeah that is also another thing i have to add which is too ignore the case of the character which i will get to later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the fact that replace funciton doesn't alter existing string ( as @MadProgrammer mentioned - string are immutable in java). Instead it yield another String.

So simply replacing

```
bucket.replace(promptuser.charAt(i), "in the");
```

to

```
bucket = bucket.replace(promptuser.charAt(i), "in the");
```

Should do the trick. Although:

1) It would be horribly inefficient
2) I feel like you solving task wrong.

Comment: i tried it out but doesnt work becuase for the .indexOf the following error shows The method indexOf(int) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

and for the .replace the error shows The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, String)

Comment: Yes, but that's completely different compiling issues with your code:1) is due your parentheses misplaced. Should be  "bucket.indexOf(promptuser.charAt(i))> -1" instead of "bucket.indexOf(promptuser.charAt(i)> -1)". Secind is due to the fact that replace work either char to char or string to string. Whereas you trying char to string - so you would need to convert first char to string. Like this: replace(promptuser.charAt(i), "in the") -> replace(String.valueOf(promptuser.charAt(i)), "in the") or replace("" + promptuser.charAt(i), "in the")